# NetworkManager add dns entries when connecting to certain dhcp servers

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I have an owncloud server on my home network that uses ssl certificates. As a result, clients need to connect using the server's FQDN: `owncloud.example.org`.

I am using an dynamic dns service to map my server's public ip address to the server's FQDN.

However, if a client machine is on my home network, I can only connect to my server using the local network address provided by my router and not the public one.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to configure NetworkManager to reconfigure the bundled dnsmasq server based on the wifi network ssid.

Basically if I am connected to a wifi network whos ssid is `home`, then add this entry to the dnsmasq config to resolve `owncloud.example.org` to my server's local ip:

```
address=/owncloud.example.org/192.168.0.200
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate suggestion. If you have the option, perhaps you could set this at your DHCP server? I use pfSense as a DHCP server and DNS server on my LAN. You could then run an internal DNS server that would resolve your name for you.

Might that be a possibility?

Comment: My home DHCP server is a feature of the gateway box that belongs to my internet service provider. Changing its behaviour is likely to be very difficult.